# how to change .multiple in upgrade to rust clap v4

Tags: rust, clap

I am trying to upgrade rust code from clap v3.22.2 to v4.0.8 and faced the problem how to change Arg::multiple. This is piece of code:

```
Arg::new("relfs")
    required(true)
    multiple(true)
```

So I get an error

```
error[E0599]: no method named `multiple` found for struct `Arg` in the current scope
   --> src/bin/reo.rs:178:26
    |
178 |                         .multiple(true)
    |                          ^^^^^^^^ method not found in `Arg`
```

I already tried to `Arg::action` as written in https://github.com/clap-rs/clap/issues/3772 but couldn't.
How can replace deprecated `multiple`?

Comment: See [ArgGroup::multiple](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/builder/struct.ArgGroup.html#method.multiple). Seems you have to use an "argument group" instead of an argument now?

Answer (score 1):

Eventually [changelog](https://github.com/clap-rs/clap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) helped me. There is the information what has been changed and how to update.
In my case it was deprecated `multiple`.